# 'init' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: swift, access-levels, xcode10.3

```
public class SelectedValue {
    static let sharedInstance = SelectedValue()
    public var reportPostId : Int? = nil
    public var report_GroupId : Int? = nil
    public var postType : String? = nil

}
```

'init' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level
Please help me to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Post code, not screenshots

Comment: public class SelectedValue {
    
    public static let sharedInstance = SelectedValue()
    public var reportPostId : Int? = nil
    public var report_GroupId : Int? = nil
    public var postType : String? = nil
}

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code posted and you don't have to initialize optional values to nil

Answer (score 2):

As it says, the `init` method (that you probably called without it's name) is `private`. make it more `public` to access it.

Click on the gray lines that say *'init' declared here* to jump to the source of the issue.
[image]

**Note that** `MyClass()` is equal to `MyClass.init()`. that means you are calling the `init` method each time you build an object.

And **also note that** if you don't specify the *access level*, it will be `internal` by default.

So this:

```
class MyClass { }
```

is equal to:

```
internal class MyClass {}
```

So **you should change it to**:

```
public MyClass { }
```

Comment: Hey, I tried but not working as I edit question.

Comment: As I mentioned, click on the gray message to see what is `internal`.

Comment: Worked. It was my fault. It was syntax error. I wrote Alamofire.Request instead of Alamofire.request